# asynchronous code not working with event listener

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, fetch, es6-promise

*Edited for clarity and to reflect changes:

Hello. I'm struggling to understand why my async functions are working just fine individually, and when chained together, but not when chained together and fired off in an event listener....

worth noting: when i try to run this without an even listener, data passes from my app, through my post route, and to my endpoint the way it should, it is then returned to my app through the correct route, etc. However, i do get an error in the console that says :

```
error SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

however, when i try to run my chain of async functions on the click of a dom element i don't get the above error, data is passed to my post route, i can log the object that is posted:

```
Object: null prototype] { zipcode: '97206', feel: 'confused' }
```

but then my server doesn't save any data, and my get route is never triggered, and nothing gets sent back to my app.......

i'm fairly lost.....

full server and app code below:

server:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));

//test values
let projectData = {
  date: "today",
  temp: "38",
  feelings: "confused"
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {

});

app.post("/postData", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  projectData = {
    date: req.body.date,
    temp: req.body.temp,
    feelings: req.body.feelings
  }
  console.log("post route was hit, saved:", projectData);
  res.redirect("/")
});

app.get("/getData", (req, res) => {
  console.log("getData route was hit, sent: ", projectData)
  res.send(projectData);
})

app.listen(3000, (req, res) => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

app

```
let newDate = getDate();
const apiKey = "5fd7b3a253e67a551e88ff34a92b9e02";
const baseURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?";

// zip=${}&APPID=${}&units=metric;

const userData = {};

// returns the date //
function getDate() {
  let d = new Date();
  let newDate = d.getMonth() + "." + d.getDate() + "." + d.getFullYear();
  return newDate;
}

//constructs string for api call, adds temp to userData object
const getData = async (apiUrl, zip, key) => {
  const url = `${apiUrl}zip=${zip}&APPID=${key}&units=metric`;
  const result = await fetch(url);
  try {
    let newData = await result.json()
    // console.log(newData.main.temp)
    userData.temp = newData.main.temp
  }catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);  
  }
}

// getData(baseURL, 97206, apiKey)
// .then(result  => {
// console.log(userData)
// })

//saves contents of userData Object to server
const postData = async (url, data) => {
  const result = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  try {
    const newData = await result.json();
    // console.log(newData);
    return newData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};

// postData('/postData', userData);


//updates interface with projectData values from server
const updateUI = async url => {
  const result = await fetch(url);
  try {
    const newData = await result.json();
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = newData.date;
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = newData.temp;
    document.getElementById("feelings").innerHTML = newData.feelings;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};

// updateUI("/getData")



// THIS WORKS

userData.date = newDate;
userData.feelings = document.getElementById("feel").value;
const zipCode = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
getData(baseURL, 97206, apiKey).then(result => {
  postData("/postData", userData).then(result => {
    updateUI("/getData");
  });
});


// THIS DOESNT WORK
// document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", e => {
//   userData.date = newDate;
//   userData.feelings = document.getElementById("feel").value;
//   const zipCode = document.getElementById("zipcode").value;
//   getData(baseURL, zipCode, apiKey).then(result => {
//     postData("/postData", userData).then(result => {
//       updateUI("/getData");
//     });
//   });

// });
```

EDIT:

I realized that the information that was being passed through the post route when my async functions are fired off by an event listener was actually just the form input element values, rather than the contents of the fetch/post request. after i removed the name attributes from the form inputs, i'm getting no data at all hitting my post route......yet the corosponding function works fine with not in the event listener.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so post it as part of your question. If you aren't getting an error message then try adding diagnostic logging to your code to make sure things are firing off when you expect.

Comment: i'm getting this error code when NOT using the event listener, (however, this is when data is actually hitting my post route and getting saved and logged to the console)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
however, when i use the event listener, i get no error, nothing hits the post route, and nothing is saved into my object on my server....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, the syntax error was solved by using .text() instead of .json() on the results of my post request.

adding e.preventDefault() as the first line of my event listener callback fixed the event listener, and now everything is working as it should.